# DELETE command with SELECT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried below delete command but I don't know why its not working:

```
DELETE FROM beteg
WHERE beteg.taj IN ( 
SELECT beteg.taj COUNT (ellatas.id) as "ellátások száma"
FROM ellatas RIGHT JOIN beteg ON ellatas.beteg = beteg.taj
WHERE "ellátások száma" = 0
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
delete from beteg
    where not exists (select 1
                      from ellatas e
                      where e.beteg = beteg.taj
                     );
```

This deletes everything in `beteg` that does not have a corresponding row in `ellatas`.

Your query has multiple issues:

- A column alias is used in the `where` clause.
- You are using `IN` with two columns in the subquery and one in the outer query.
- The subquery has no `GROUP BY`, but is using `COUNT()`.

In any case, the above query is simpler and should  have better performance.